# What are the changes in ios 6 as compare to previous versions of xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I was build an app in ios 4.1 but now i am using ios 6 to build it but there are problems in pushviewcontroller and orientation methods. So can any one tell me what are the changes have brought in ios 6?

Comment: pushViewController modally has changed slightly. The method is depricated but still works fine. However, you should check the docs for its replacement. (basically just withAnimation:NO/YES must be added or so.) Its replacement is availalbe since 4.0. Builds for before 4.0 are virtually impossible as the affected devices's processor architecture is no longer supported in SDK 6.0.

Comment: shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation is no longer called in the manner you are used to. Instead of maintaining those methods in all subclasses of UIViewController you setup it properly within your project settings in xcode. For individual responses if not all view controllers support the same orientations, use "supportedInterfaceOrientations" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think that best solution is to stick to official apple documentation. So according to that I use following methods and everything is working very well on iOS 5 and 6. In all of your ViewControllers override following methods.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Methods for iOS 6, first method returns supported orientation mask (as their name indicate), you can change it into Landscape or what suites you best.

```
-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; //UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait or LandscapeLeft ... 
}
```

second one thats tells your VC which is preferred interface orientation when VC is going to be displayed.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait; //tells your VC in which orientation it should be presented, if you set Porttrait it would be in Portrait or otherwise ...
}
```

This solution is working